# When is Non-Max Suppression used in Object Detection

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

Is non-max suppression for bounding boxes obtained from a Region Proposal Network performed during training? From what I gather, NMS is not differentiable-- in which case, it can't be performed during training (it is also mentioned in this [issue](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474386/do-we-need-to-back-propagate-through-non-max-suppression-layers)). But does that mean that the boxes go into the subsequent layers such as ROI Pooling without NMS?

Where in the pipeline is NMS used and how?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Is non-max suppression for bounding boxes obtained from a Region Proposal Network performed during training?**

Yes, according to the Faster-RCNN paper it states,

> Some RPN proposals highly overlap with each
> other. To reduce redundancy, we adopt non-maximum
> suppression (NMS) on the proposal regions based on
> their cls scores. We fix the IoU threshold for NMS
> at 0.7, which leaves us about 2000 proposal regions
> per image. As we will show, NMS does not harm the
> ultimate detection accuracy, but substantially reduces
> the number of proposals.

So, NMS on proposals is not essential, but it reduces computation without significant loss of performance.

**2. NMS is not differentiable-- in which case, it can't be performed during training**

According to the paper, authors use *Approximate joint training* which is,

> *Approximate joint training*: In this solution, the
> RPN and Fast R-CNN networks are merged into one
> network during training as in Figure 2. In each SGD
> iteration, the forward pass generates region proposals which are treated just like fixed, pre-computed
> proposals when training a Fast R-CNN detector. The
> backward propagation takes place as usual, where for
> the shared layers the backward propagated signals
> from both the RPN loss and the Fast R-CNN loss
> are combined. This solution is easy to implement. But
> this solution ignores the derivative w.r.t. the proposal
> boxes’ coordinates that are also network responses,
> so is approximate.

So if *Approximate joint training* method is used (which is common use), each proposals are treated as pre-computed proposal. This method might not be mathematically legitimate, but hey, it does the job.

Comment: Based on the 2nd part of your answer, how does approximate joint training help perform non-max suppression without giving any issue during back-propagation?
In general, how do you perform nms without any error during backprop?

Comment: there are no backprop through nms because proposals are considered as a constant rather than function of weights in the network.